# Postgresql jsonb column with spring jpa nativequery issue

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, jsonb

I have a native query defined in a spring JpaRepositroy as:

```
@Query(value="Select * from Employee WHERE....", nativeQuery=true)
List<Employee> getEmployees(....)
```

In entity, I have a jsonb field defined as:

```
import com.vladmihalcea.hibernate.type.json.JsonBinaryType;
....
@Type(type = "jsonb")
@Column(name = "properties", columnDefinition = "jsonb")
private ObjectNode properties;
```

This setup works perfect, and it fetches the records for me correctly.

But if I try to fetch only some specific columns by changing query as:

```
@Query(value="Select emp_name, properties from Employee WHERE....", nativeQuery=true)
List<Object[]> getEmployees(....)
```

This gives me error as:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: 1111
```

And I get this error only if properties field is in SELECT clause, else this too works fine.

What is the reason? And how to get it working with properties field?

Comment: What hibernate and hibernate-types versions do you use?

Comment: I am using spring 2.3(hibernate 5.4.20), with hibernate-types 2.9.11.